# Rails3: Routing Error uninitialized constant SiteConfiguration

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes, uninitialized-constant

I know this has been asked before and I have found many questions that are similar to mine but ever where the answer seems to be the same 'a typo', but I've looked at my code time and time again and can't point the error/typo out, I'm beginning to think its more then just a typo: here's my code with exact spellings for file names:

i created the table with the following migration:

**015_create_site_configurations.rb**

```
class CreateSiteConfigurations < ActiveRecord::Migration

  def self.up
    create_table "site_configurations" do |t|
      t.column :config_type,    :string
      t.column :value,          :string

    end

  end

  def self.down
    drop_table "site_configurations"
  end
end
```

Controller for this class

**manage_site_configurations_controller.rb**

```
class ManageSiteConfigurationsController < AdminController

  active_scaffold :site_configurations do |config|
    config.columns = [:config_type, :value]
    config.create.columns = [:config_type, :value]
  end

end
```

Since im using this for ActiveScaffold here's a snippet from **application.rb**

```
  def self.active_scaffold_controller_for(klass)
    return ManageUsersController if klass == User
    return ManagePagesController if klass == Page
    return ManageSiteConfigurationsController if klass == SiteConfiguration
    return "#{klass}ScaffoldController".constantize rescue super
  end
```

and this is what I used for my routes

```
resources :manage_site_configurations do as_routes end
```

I'd really appreciate it if some one can point the error out..

Answer (score 0):

You have the migration, but do you have the model in app/models/ generated by

```
rails g active_scaffold Model attr1:type attr2:type
rake db:migrate
```

Otherwise it could be that

```
active_scaffold :site_configurations do |config|
```

should be

```
active_scaffold :site_configuration do |config|
```

At least they don't pluralize ':company' in the example on https://github.com/activescaffold/active_scaffold/wiki/getting-started

```
active_scaffold :company do |config|
  config.label = "Customers"
  config.columns = [:name, :phone, :company_type, :comments]
  list.columns.exclude :comments
  list.sorting = {:name => 'ASC'}
  columns[:phone].label = "Phone #"
  columns[:phone].description = "(Format: ###-###-####)"
end
```